# No idea why my MVC Entity-Framework app cannot find elements in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Just found some live bugs on my blog and I have no clue as to why they are happening. If you want to see the full big ugly message just go [here](http://www.nerdlythings.com)

The code that is giving me the issue is this:

```
    NerdlyContext db = new NerdlyContext();
    public IEnumerable<Post> GetIndexPage(int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 5;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var posts = from p in db.Posts
                    where p.Published == true && p.Archived == false
                    orderby p.DateCreated descending
                    select p;
        var result = posts.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
        return result;
    }
```

I tried to see test is my doing a quick db.Posts.FirstorDefault() to see if it was getting anything, but it seems like it is not hitting my db at all. I opened up the db in SSMS and all the data is the same. I am hosted on discountasp.net and re-copied the exact connection string back over to make sure nothing accidentally got changed. Still not working. The only recent changes I made was I tried to add some more dbset items, but that through an error on the package manage console, so I undid all the changed, rebuilt the solution, and now I got this..

## Update

Digging deeper into when it instantiates my DbContext, it say the change tracker is throwing an error.

Comment: As a side note, please don't use `==` on boolean values unless you actually need to perform an *equality* comparison with another boolean variable. `where p.Published && !p.Archived` is simpler.

Comment: Are you one of the people who refers to IE as "the internet" ? If not, then why are you referring to ASP.NET MVC framework as MVC (which is a language independent design pattern) ?

Comment: I was relying on the intuitiveness of the SO community there teresko. I assumed that if I tag it with ASP.NET MVC as well as another microsoft techlogy, EF, that people would assume I mean the asp.net mvc project, not a design pattern in general.

Answer (score 1):

Is your connection string correct?

Can you set a breakpoint and inspect db.Posts? You should be able to drill in to see both the query and the connection string. Perhaps that can point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Ya the connection string is correct. The only thing I see off-putting in there is that is say the State = Closed.

Answer (score 1):

Likely to be an issue with the Connection String. Have you specified a connection string in the constructor of your DBContext class, like below:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext 
        { 

            public YourContext () : base("YourConnection")
            {

            }

//DBSets here
        }
```

"YourConnection" is set in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="....." />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Didn't have the constructor in there before. Just tried it and I am still throwing the same error.

Comment: If there is data in the database and db.Posts.FirstorDefault() returns nothing it likely a connection issue. Can you connect using your connection string via other method (SSMS, online console etc...)?

Comment: Yes, i have that same database it should be hitting open now in SSMS

Comment: If you can generate a connection string which matches the one you are using then I'd be stumped. I typically test the connection string by connecting to the db in Visual Studio and checking the connection string property.

Comment: +1 for going into some effort for trying to fix it. I got it working now. I will post an answer with the steps I took.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I was right on board with all of you thinking this was a connection string issue. Those were all fine though.

1. What I ended up doing was removing all my previous migration classes from the project.
2. Deleted the MigrationsHistory folder from my database.
3. Changing the Configuration of the Migration thingy to automatic migrations
4. re-ran the Update-Database Command. (It gave me an error say Posts already exists)
5. Then with no faith at all, I re-ran it and boom, my data is back

So why does it work now? I haven't a damn clue..